# ANSI C: Declare a pointer of type "array of string"

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

I have a structure like this

```
struct {
  int    id;
  char   str00[10];
  char   str01[10];
  char   str03[10];
  char   str04[10];
  ...
}   myStructure;
```

All strXX have the same size. I would like to access them via an array (strArray), like this :

```
strcpy(strArray[i], strValue);
```

How to declare strArray ?

I used this:

```
char   (*strArray)[][10] = (void *)&myStructure.str00;
```

It's working, but I have to code the strcpy like this

```
strcpy((*strArray)[i], strValue);
```

... and I don't like this :-)

Is there another way to declare strArray ?

Thanks for your ideas and help.

Comment: A pointer to array needs to be dereferenced no matter what. You'll need to get used to the syntax or use normal pointers.

Comment: Why do you want to have individual names for the members instead of simply defining them as one array of arrays in the first place?

Answer (score 3):

You almost had it, the correct pointer type is simply `char (*ptr)[10]`.

Naively, you *could* use this pointer type to iterate over the struct members, but doing so would invoke undefined behavior. Because strictly speaking, a pointer can only point at single item or an array, and if we use pointer arithmetic to go beyond that single item/array, we invoke undefined behavior.

I'll include an example still, for the sake of demonstrating array pointer arithmetic:

```
// BAD CODE, it relies on undefined behavior!

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
  int    id;
  char   str00[10];
  char   str01[10];
  char   str02[10];
  char   str03[10];
} myStructure;


int main(void)
{
  myStructure ms = { 0 };
  char (*ptr)[10] = &ms.str00;

  for(size_t i=0; i<4; i++)
  {
    strcpy(ptr[i], "hello ");
    strcat(ptr[i], (char[]){i+'0', '\0'});
  }

  puts(ms.str00);
  puts(ms.str01);
  puts(ms.str02);
  puts(ms.str03);

  return 0;
}
```

The *proper* solution is to instead use a union, so that you can access the members either individually, or as an array:

```
typedef union {
  struct              // anonymous struct, requires a standard C compiler
  {
    char str00[10];
    char str01[10];
    char str02[10];
    char str03[10];
  };
  char array[4][10];
} str_t;

typedef struct {
  int    id;
  str_t  str;
} myStructure;


strcpy(ms.str.array[i], ...); // access as array
puts(ms.str.str00); // access as individual item
```

Comment: I have a feeling that padding still makes both solutions relying on undefined behavior and non-portable.

Comment: Unfortunately, although the `union` alternative indeed avoids UB, it is not guaranteed to do what the OP wants, because there can be padding between the arrays in the `struct`, but there will not be any between the elements of the 2D array.

Comment: Indeed, the precence of struct padding is implementation-defined and depends on possible alignment requirements for the specific system.

Answer (score 2):

The cleanest way to define `strArray` as requested would be to make it an array of pointers to the (first elements of the) arrays in `myStructure`:

```
char *strArray[] = { myStructure.str00, myStructure.str01, myStructure.str03, myStructure.Str04, … };
```

With this definition, `strArray[i]` is initialized to the corresponding member of the structure, such as `myStructure.str01`. Note that `myStructure.str01` will be automatically converted to a pointer to its first element, so `strArray[i]` is a pointer to the first `char` in one of the arrays.

Then `strArray[i][j]` is `char` `j` of array `i`.

(Incidentally, you skip `str02` in your sample code. I do not know why but have retained that in the code above.)

An alternative method would be to use a union, which can be done in various ways, one of which is:

```
struct
{
    int    id;
    union
    {
        struct
        {
            char   str00[10];
            char   str01[10];
            char   str03[10];
            char   str04[10];
            ...
        };
        char strArray[number of arrays][10];
    };
} myStructure;
```

That is generally a poor design, as it is needlessly confusing. (While this has a technical possibility of failure due to padding between the individually defined arrays, assertions can be used to ensure this does not occur, or rather to detect when it does.)

Most often, we would simply define the strings as an array of arrays:

```
struct
{
    int id;
    char str[number of arrays][10];
} my Structure;
```

Then the members would always be referred to by index, such as `myStructure.str[1]`, and not by individual names, such as `myStructure.str01`.

Comment: Even more so than because it is needlessly complicated, the `union` approach is a poor choice because it is not guaranteed to work as desired as a result of the possibility of padding between the `struct` members.  That it may work as desired on some conforming implementations but not on others makes that just nasty.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Already addressed, in a nearly simultaneous edit.

Comment: I see your edit, but I think you're underplaying the issue.  Also, I only reluctantly agree that the proposed usage of assertions is appropriate for that feature.  I would much rather see their use reserved to asserting *program* behaviors, as opposed to characteristics of the C implementation.  You have my upvote anyway, though.